# How to implement auto compile like java Servlet , PHP CMS template?

Tags: java, php, templates, smarty

I want to implement a small PHP template engine like smarty which would allow me to write my own php tag(if,for ..)

And now ,my problem is how to compile automatic when the template file was modified?

For example: Servlet . When we modified the servlet and waited for seconds ,the eclipse would tell you that the modified servlet class was recompiled !

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the modified date, between the cached compiled template, and the source file.

```
$cacheFileAge = @filemtime($this->cacheFile); //Get Time
foreach(array_merge(array($template),$this->snipFiles) as $f)
  if($cacheFileAge < filemtime($f)) //Compare every template to cache file
    return $this->parse(file_get_contents($template)); //If cache file older than one, re-compile it
debugLog("Using Cached file ({$this->cacheFile})");
include($this->cacheFile); //use cached file
```

This example was taken from another php template project [HAMLE](https://github.com/cseufert/hamle/blob/master/php/hamle/_.php)

Comment: thank you!and can you explain how this cache file work?why we need cache?

Comment: You will be best to parse your template file, find your custom tags, replace them with php code (perhaps use `regex_replace_cb()` or similar. Then save this generated file to your cache localtion, then when you wish to display this page, you can simply `include()` the file from the cache location and it will display your template and execute the code within.

Comment: thanks,  one more question,where should I do these SQL selects ? In parsing?

Comment: Depends, if the content is static, then put results into compiled template, however if they are dynamic, put function calls to queries into compiled template.